# Inject angular application as iframe working in chrome but now working on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

[image]I have one iframe
`<iframe src="url of angular application" id="tour-iframe" style="width:100%;height:100%;"></iframe>`
It works fine in chrome but not working in Mozilla Firefox, can anyone help me on this.
It is works in chrome desktop browser but again in mobile chrome browser it is not working.

1. working in chrome desktop.
2. not working in firefox
3. not working in mobile chrome.

The angular application which is given in the url and the website which injects the iframe both have ssl enabled.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to give more details about what is "not working" to get some help :)

Comment: content of angular application is not injecting to the iframe

Comment: Have you checked your browser development logs for errors and/or warnings? Please be as complete as possible. Without any information, other then 'not working', it is difficult to help you.

Comment: updated with the warning i am getting in console

Comment: Both sites, the main and the angular application are on https?